# Criando rota cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3

Intenção: 
acessar http://localhost/api/usuarios/[action]

criei a rota

```
Router::scope('/api', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json']);
    $routes->resources('Usuarios');    
});
```

está funcionando, mas quando acesso o endereço 
http://localhost/usuarios/[action] funciona da mesma forma, eu não quero que este endereço esteja disponível, apenas o endereço /api

arquivo `routes.php`

```
Router::defaultRouteClass('DashedRoute');

Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {

    $routes->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home']);

    $routes->connect('/pages/*', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display']);

    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});

 //essa é a rota que eu criei
Router::scope('/api', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json']);
    $routes->resources('Usuarios');    
});

Plugin::routes();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linha `$routes->resources('Usuarios');` vai criar todas as rotas possíveis. A [documentação oficial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html) tem alguns exemplos de como você pode limitar isso.
Exemplo da documentação do CakePHP:

```
$routes->resources('Usuarios', [
    'only' => ['index', 'view']
]);
```

Isso restringe a quantidade de rotas criadas, você deve querer apenas a index, então pode tirar a view.